# Recaptcha with "required" attribute appears as invalid with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, recaptcha

I am using recaptcha in my project. I used java script to generate captcha.I used below code.

```
Recaptcha.create(private_key, 'captchadiv', 
        {
            theme: "clean",
            callback : function()
            {
                $("#recaptcha_response_field").attr("required",true);
            }
        });
```

It generates recaptcha but the problem is when the page loads first time it appears as invalid like the below image.

[image]

What can be solution ??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
if($('#recaptcha_response_field').val().length > 0){
    $('#recaptcha_response_field').prop('required', true);
}
```

Simply check for text in the input on the page load. Further, use `.prop()` as opposed to `.attr()` for this.

Comment: Your's one is not working. Actually I would like make recaptcha field as a part of a form.There are other input fields in that form. I would like to get the whole form data when I'll submit the form.  How can I do that? Thanks